# Python: Random 4 digit password guessing, can't figure out 1 problem

Tags: python, passwords

I'm new to Python. I have a program that lets you guess a random 4-digit password. For example, if the password is `5530`, if I guess one `5` inside (such as `5111`), it says I guessed 2 numbers correctly. If the password is `5535`, it says I guessed 3 numbers correctly.

But in reality, it interpreted the single `5` in my answer to be correct for the other `5`s. I want it to only say I guessed one number correctly if there and two or three `5`s, two correct if I typed two `5`s for `5530`, three correct if I type three `5`s for `5535`.

```
import random

no1 = random.randint(0, 9)
no2 = random.randint(0, 9)
no3 = random.randint(0, 9)
no4 = random.randint(0, 9)

password = str(no1) + str(no2) + str(no3) + str(no4)
count = 0

if no1 % 2 == 0:
    count += 1

if no2 % 2 == 0:
    count += 1

if no3 % 2 == 0:
    count += 1

if no4 % 2 == 0:
    count += 1

print(password)
print(f"Hint: The password consists of {count} even number(s)")

guess = input("Guess the 4 numbers: ")
present = 0

if str(no1) in guess:
    present += 1

if str(no2) in guess:
    present += 1

if str(no3) in guess:
    present += 1

if str(no4) in guess:
    present += 1

if present == 4:

    if guess == password:
        print("Congrats! You have guessed the password correctly.")

    else:
        print("All the numbers are present but not in the correct sequence.")
        print(f"You did not make it! The password is {password}.")

else:
    print(f"{present} number(s) of your guess are present in the password.")
    print(f"You did not make it! The password is {password}.")
```

**P.S.** I expect my code below may be shortened with `range` and stuff, but I'm not confident in doing that, so can someone help me out with that?

Comment: count = len([num for num in str(password) if int(num) % 2 == 0])                   present=len([num for num in str(password) if str(num) in str(guess)])

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if str(no1) in guess:
    present += 1
if str(no2) in guess:
    present += 1
if str(no3) in guess:
    present += 1
if str(no4) in guess:
    present += 1
```

to:

```
present += guess[0] == str(no1)
present += guess[1] == str(no2)
present += guess[2] == str(no3)
present += guess[3] == str(no4)
```

Another way:

```
rand_nums = [no1, no2, no3, no4]
for i in range(4)
    if (int(guess[i]) == rand_nums[i]):
        present += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it's better than my current one but I want it to work even if its the wrong order, is it possible? If I use the code from the answers, I'm not able to get the output that my password is not in the correct sequence. For example if the password is 5530 and I use the answers provided by you guys and guess 1155, I get 0 number(s) of my guess is present in the password, but I want it to say 2 number(s) of my guess are present in the password.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare each number from password with each number from guess. To do that, you have to access guess with an index. Like so:

```
if str(no1) in guess[0]:

    present += 1
```

Comment: Thanks but if I use the code from the answers, I'm not able to get the output that my password is not in the correct sequence. For example if the password is 5530 and I use the answers provided by you guys and guess 1155, I get 0 number(s) of my guess is present in the password, but I want it to say 2 number(s) of my guess are present in the password.

Comment: Well, you could make a new variable called, for example, tick. Make it equal to zero, and use it to see if the password and guess match. On the other hand, use present in the way that you used it originally, and in the end make if/else statements where you check if the password is correct by examining 'tick', and check the presence by examining 'present'.

Comment: Basically, use code from the answer with 'tick, and then under it add the code that you originally used. There probably is a more economic way to do all that, but I'm not so familiar with syntax currently, so I can't easily check it in my IDE.

Comment: Although its kinda confusing I'll try it thanks